# How to put ChartLabel of BoxWhisker top of the frame?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, charts

I would like to put chartlabel above the frame (highlited place). Any idea?

```
ft=20;
{col1, col2, col3, col4} = {Red, Darker@Green, Blue, Orange};
    chartLab = {Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(-1\)]\)", Bold, col1,
         ft], Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(0\)]\)", Bold, col2, 
        ft], Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(1\)]\)", Bold, col3, 
        ft]};

d[\[Mu]_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], 1], 100];

BoxWhiskerChart[{d[1], d[2], d[3]}, ChartLabels -> chartLab]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{d[1], d[2], d[3]}, ChartLabels -> chartLab] /. 
 Rule[FrameTicks, {a_, {b_, c_}}] :> Rule[FrameTicks, {a, {c, b}}]
```

[image]

Comment: There is really no other way than meddling with the graphics structure post-hoc?

Comment: @IstvánZachar, not any i know of. We can also use `DisplayFunction` (that is, add the option `DisplayFunction ->  ReplaceAll[Rule[FrameTicks, {a_, {b_, c_}}] :> Rule[FrameTicks, {a, {c, b}}]]` inside `BoxWhiskerChart[...]`)  but this is also post-processing.